# How do I fix this commerce_auction_node_presave error message?

Tags: commerce

I am working on a reverse auction for our youth group.  I'm using D7 with the commerce_auction module.   I ran into the error below when setting up the content type for the auction:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in commerce_auction_node_presave() (line 260 of /public_html/catz/sites/all/modules/commerce_auction/commerce_auction.module).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_product. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7697 of /public_html/catz/includes/common.inc).
```

for the first notice, line 260 contains this: $product_reference = $product_reference[0];

Does anyone know how to fix this error?  There's not a lot of commenting as yet on this auction module, so I can't find a solution.

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */

```
function commerce_auction_node_presave($node) {
  $types = variable_get('commerce_auction_display_types', array());
  if (in_array($node->type, $types) !== FALSE) {
    $product_reference = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_product');
    $product_reference = $product_reference[0];
    $product = commerce_product_load($product_reference['product_id']);
    $price = field_get_items('commerce_product', $product, 'commerce_price');
    $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = $price[0]['amount'];
    $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code'] = $price[0]['currency_code'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code below :

```
 $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = $price[0]['amount'];
    $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code'] = $price[0]['currency_code'];
```

with

```
 $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = $price['und'][0]['amount'];
        $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code'] = $price['und'][0]['currency_code'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that error by updating (or moving) to the 7.x-2.x-dev version of the module. [`commerce_auction_node_presave()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_auction/blob/7.x-2.x/commerce_auction.module#L246) has been changed to use the following code.

```
function commerce_auction_node_presave($node) {
  $types = variable_get('commerce_auction_display_types', array());
  if (in_array($node->type, $types) !== FALSE) {
    $product_reference = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_product');
    if (!empty($product_reference)) {
      $product_reference = $product_reference[0];
      $product = commerce_product_load($product_reference['product_id']);
      $price = field_get_items('commerce_product', $product, 'commerce_price');
      $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] = $price[0]['amount'];
      $node->auction_starting_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['currency_code'] = $price[0]['currency_code'];
    }
  }
}
```

Differently from the 7.x-1.x-dev version, the code now verifies `$product_reference` is not an empty value (for example, an empty array), before trying to use `$product_reference[0]`, which is sufficient to avoid the error you are seeing.